# I want my bash program sees a date different from the actual

Tags: bash, date

I need a bash script that sets a date for my program. The program must work with a date different from the current one. Is it possible? With:

```
#!/bin/sh

date 122511462014.30 && myprogram
```

I get the following message error

> date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted

because my script runs with no root privileges.

Comment: I presume, just changing `myprogram` is out of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that. `date` changes the date for the entire system.

You need something like [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime)